# Octave: which method is more efficient

Tags: math, optimization, octave, mathematical-optimization

I am trying some machine learning algorithms in GNU Octave like the squared error cost function.  The text I have says the proper vectorized forumula is:

```
J = (X * theta - y)' * (X * theta - y) * (1/(2*m)
```

where X is an  `m x n+1` matrix, theta is a `n+1 x 1` vector, and y is a `m x 1` vector.  My question is whether this second way is a bit faster:

```
J = sum((X * theta - y).^2) * (1/(2*m))
```

since it only calculates `X * theta -y` once.  Being new to octave, which seems to run in a very temperamental environment on windows, I don't know how to do benchmarking myself.

Since this is more of curiosity than anything, feel free to tell me it just doesn't even matter.

Comment: Are you sure the formulae yield identical results? If you want to optimize, why don't you write:
 `TMP = (X * theta - y)`
 `J = TMP' * TMP * (1/(2*m))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This checks wallclock time:

```
octave:2> tic; sleep(3); toc
Elapsed time is 3.00161 seconds.
octave:3> help tic
```

The resolutions is not too great, hence you might want to run a calculation several times in a loop.

To measure CPU time, use `cputime`:

```
octave:7> cputime()
ans =  0.21000
octave:8> sleep(3)
octave:9> cputime()
ans =  0.21000
```

Comment: Thanks, those will be useful.